# Allow users to moderate taxonomy terms

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Is there a way to allow users to moderate nodes and their comments by taxonomy terms? And also allow other moderators to add users to to that term as well? It seems that the standard roles aren't granular enough. I don't want users assigned to a "moderator" role to be able to moderate ALL nodes and comments, just those within a particular taxonomy term.

Basically allowing each term to be a "discussion board" where a group of users are the moderators of that term. Similar to how Reddit works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) - access control for user roles based on taxonomy categories (vocabulary, terms).

- Automatically controls access to nodes (based on their taxonomy terms).
- Configuration page for each user role.
- Three node access permission types: View, Update, Delete.
- Two term access types: View tag, Add tag.

Answer (score 0):

[Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) is another possibility that is more focussed on the people instead of categories.